# What is the purpose of rootViewController and when would you switch it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

This is a general question regarding ios development.
What is exactly the purpose of the window.rootViewController? In which cases you would choose to switch the rootViewController and in which cases you would prefer to push a new view controller on top of the current one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to list the ways I used the rootViewController:

1. If you have a background process that is always running no matter which view controller is showing, by using rootViewController you have access to that particular view controller on the screen and can act accordingly (you can do push, pop, modal, etc).
2. Another thing would be using it for changing the view completely to a different (usually illegal transition), for example you are not able to ever push the SplitView but you can cheat and use the rootViewController property to do that.